# razor count items

Tags: razor, count, umbraco, if-statement

How can i do this in razor:

- when there is one item, i only want this item to be displayed. (item in fotoGallerij)
- when there are more items, i want all of them (like the code bellow, working)

How can i make this if (i think) structure in razor (c# / umbraco)?

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext

<ul class="image-gallery">
@foreach (var item in @Model.fotoGallerij)
{
<li>
<a class="gallery grouped" href="/ImageGen.ashx?height=500&amp;constrain=true&amp;crop=resize&amp;image=@item.Image.umbracoFile" title="">

<img src="/ImageGen.ashx?width=71&amp;height=73&amp;crop=resize&amp;image=@item.Image.umbracoFile" alt=""/></a>
 </li>
 }
</ul>
 <script>
    $("a.gallery").colorbox({rel:'grouped'});
</script>
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Is the desired markup the same for only 1 item? In other words, what do you want it to look like with only one? Cause if there's only one, your original code should still work fine to display it.

Comment: If there is only one image, i want this one bigger and with a link (allready done that).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Razor is in effect C#, so anything you can do with C#, you can do with Razor. Something like this should work:

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext
@if (Model.fotoGallerij.Count() == 1)
{
    // Display only the one here...
}
else if (Model.fotoGallerij.Count() > 1)
{
    // Loop through the list of items here...
}
```

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'MVCApp3.Models.CompanyListView' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'MVCApp3.Models.CompanyListView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @JulesBartow, the code above is in reference to umbraco. Model.fotoGallerij is handled by umbraco dynamically and returns a  DynamicNodeList which does have a Count method associated with it. This wouldn't apply to a standard MVC app.